# Email verification before registration confirmation using Meteor and React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor, email-validation

Just learning Meteor and Reactjs by following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SHMHdIZ4l80&list=PLKfAG4yMwKkSTkCFX7HXG5GAN-fvGAQqY&index=7), which is very nice to work with. This is a registration page, by default this does not verify via email before registration is done. In a real life scenario i'll like to have the users verify their emails before registration can be concluded, as a newbie I'm poised with howto, kindly help.

```
Signupform = React.createClass({
    mixins: [ReactMeteorData],
    getMeteorData(){
        let data = {};
        data.currentUser = Meteor.user();
        return data;
    },
    getInitialState(){
        return {
            message: '',
            messageClass: 'hidden'
        }
    },
    displayError(message){
        this.setState({message: message, messageClass: 'alert alert-danger registerError'});
    },
    handleSubmit(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        this.setState({message: '', messageClass: 'hidden'});
        var that = this;
        var first_name = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.first_name).value.trim();
        var last_name = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.last_name).value.trim();
        var email = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.email).value.trim();
        var password = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.password).value.trim();
        var user = {
            email: email,
            password: password,
            profile: {
                fullname: (first_name + last_name).toLowerCase(),
                firstname: first_name,
                lastname: last_name,
                avatar: 'http://placehold.it/150x150',
                friends: []
            }
        };
        Accounts.createUser(user, function (e) {

            if (e) {
                that.displayError(e.reason);
            } else {
                FlowRouter.go('/dashboard');
            }
        })


    },
    render(){
        return (
            <div className="row">
                <div className="signup">
                    <h1>Sign Up</h1>
                    <p className="text-muted">It's free and always will be.</p>
                </div>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <div className="col-sm-9">
                        <div className="row">
                            <div className="col-sm-6 form-group">
                                <input ref="first_name" type="text" placeholder="First name"
                                       className="form-control"/>
                            </div>
                            <div className="col-sm-6 form-group">
                                <input ref="last_name" type="text" placeholder="Last name"
                                       className="form-control"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                        <div className="form-group">
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Email or mobile number" ref="email"
                                   className="form-control"/>
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <input type="password" placeholder="New password" ref="password"
                                   className="form-control"/>
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-md btn-success">Sign Up</button>
                        <span className={this.state.messageClass}>{this.state.message}</span>

                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The Meteor accounts package has a function designed for verifying an email address, but this happens after the user has created an account. `Accounts.sendVerificationEmail`

[Here is a link to the docs for it.](https://docs.meteor.com/api/passwords.html#Accounts-sendVerificationEmail)

Alternatively you can use another Accounts function called `Accounts.sendEnrollmentEmail` which emails the user a link which then redirects them back to the application to set their password and access the application.

That way you know they are using a valid email before they can use your application.

[Here is a link to the docs for that.](https://docs.meteor.com/api/passwords.html#Accounts-sendEnrollmentEmail)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you mean by verifying email before registration. If you mean to validate the existence of the email, then follow the below step.

Once the user submits the registration form, you need to send an email to the email address with somekind of one time password(OTP) a random 4 or 6 digit number. Then on the UI ask the user to enter the OTP that they have received in the email. If it matches the one you sent, then you can register the user, if not throw an error and ask them to reconfirm the email and start the loop all over again.

Note: This is not related to react or meteor in any way. This is a logical question.

Comment: Sorry for the bad grammar, what I meant is that before registration could be concluded, an email ought to be sent to the email entered so that the user clicks a link on the email before it is confirmed that it registered. Maybe it is better worded like this: "email confirmation for registration"

Comment: If you mean that an email is to be sent and the user should click on the email before it is confirmed then i would not say the user is `not registered`. I would say the user is registered, but not yet activated or verified his account. What i assumed from your question is that you need the user registration to happen only after the email is confirmed, which is what i described a simple procedure that is used by many services who accept `phone number` as their unique key.